# Are they the same in meaning: "This is September now" AND "It is September now"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, pronouns

This is from a native speaker gardener's youtube video where he tells about his roses [Roses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDCm4yFWPls) (see:5:50-5:53)

**"This is September now and a lot of my roses are still blooming."**

The structure **"This is ...."** sounded different to me, because when we talk about months, we say **"It is (name of the month)"** For instance, "It is September, June etc"

So, why does he say **"This is September now."** instead of **"It is September now"**?

Comment: "This section of the video was shot in September." He could just as well have said "It is..."

Comment: Agreed; the "this" version must mean "what you're seeing took place in September," not that the current month is September.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually say ***It's** midday now*, not ***This is** midday now* - and the same preference applies with [***It's/This is** September now.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%27s+January+now%2CIt+is+January+now%2CThis+is+January+now&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) There's nothing "wrong" with OP's cited usage, though - regardless of whether it's September *at time of speaking*, or the speaker is providing voiceover / commentary to some footage shot during last September.

Note that ***this, it,*** and ***now*** all implicitly refer to *the current contextually-relevant time*, which isn't necessarily the same thing as *time of utterance* (when the words are spoken).

***But*** - the longer the duration of the time-frame referent, the more likely we are to use ***this*** rather than ***it***. So ***This is 5 past 9 now*** is incredibly unlikely, but ***This is the twenty-first century now*** might actually be more common than ***It's the twenty-first century now***.